# Reading keyboard input in Dart

Tags: dart

I am brand new to Dart and was just trying a toy example, and am seeing `stdin.readlineSync()` only return if I enter an odd number of characters.

The toy example is very simple:

```
import "dart:io";

void main() 
{
  print('Type something and press enter:');
  String? result = stdin.readLineSync();
  print(result);
}
```

When I type an even number of characters and then hit enter, it doesn't recognize it as the end of the input and forces me to enter another string.

When I type an odd number of characters and then hit enter, it does recognize it, though, as you can see in the sample output below, it smushes it together with what I typed before (length-based). I'm guessing that since I'm on Windows, it's getting  when I hit enter.

```
C:\Users\kmort\projects>first.exe
Type something and press enter:
even number of characters.             // What I typed, even number of characters
odd item count.                        // What I typed, odd number of characters
odd item count.characters.             // Result is concatenation of first and second inputs
```

I tried it in both PowerShell and Windows console, and this behavior exists in both.

I'm running on Dart SDK version: 3.2.1 (stable) (Wed Nov 22 08:59:13 2023 +0000) on "windows_x64"

I have to be doing something wrong, or have a fundamental misunderstanding of what's going on, because it can't be this broken, right? I expect it to take the whole string when I press enter and move on, not caring about odd or even character count. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's indeed a bug with the current version of Dart. Perhaps reverting to a previous version will resolve it?

https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/53973

I can reproduce it too, it won't work in the Windows 11 terminal. If I use a bash terminal (like WSL Ubuntu or a Git Bash), it all works as expected for me.

Comment: Wow. This does not bode well for the Dart language, if a complete beginner can find an obvious bug in 20 minutes. I guess that this really isn't what Dart is meant for. Thank you for pointing out the bug report. Same thing as you, if I switch over to old-school `cmd`, it works just fine. The problem apparently only exists in Windows Terminal like you said. Good job.